# Android studio Logcat

Tags: android, logcat, activity-manager

Android's logcat (eclipse) used to show ActivityManager manager states

Like this

```
02-23 16:01:15.327: I/ActivityManager(65): Starting activity: Intent {   cmp=com.tmrepo/.Clfbpg }  
02-23 16:01:17.237: I/ActivityManager(65): Displayed activity com.tmrepo/.Clfbpg: 1777 ms (total 1777 ms)`
```

But the logcat in Android studio never shows anything related to ActivityManager.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the LogCat window, make sure "Log Level" is set to "Verbose" :

[image]

Also, By default, The LogCat only shows output from *your* app, so you might need to configure it to show output from *all* processes, including ActivityManager. This can be by unselecting "Only Show output from selected process" (next to the tabs in the LogCat panel) And selecting "No Filters" on the right.

Comment: Yes i did, it shows all the log except  'ActivityManager'

Comment: Well the 'Verbose' and 'No Filters' fixed the issue