# Strange Log.i() behavior Android Studio

Tags: java, android, logging

I'm seeing something really weird. Im making a http post request

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String strResponse = null;
            if (entity != null) {
                strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Log.i("SetupAutoCardResponse",String.valueOf(strResponse));
                Log.i("otherTest","test");
                Log.i("otherTest",strResponse);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

The only output I see in the log is `otherTest : Test`.
The logs with `strResponse` dont show up at all, and by that I mean, nothing shows. It does not look like this  `SetupAutoCardResponse : null` or `otherTest: null`. Absolutly nothing shows up. But I know I am getting a response. The expression returns `true`

Comment: Can you check which filter in your logcat window (eg. verbose or error)

Comment: @Rajesh I tried a bunch, but shouldn't it be in Info. Isn't that what the ```i``` is for?

Comment: @MohammadZarei Could you explain a little more?

Comment: I was suggesting try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29497907/3629732

Answer (score 1):

In Log, if the Messsage is Null or Blank or Empty, Log will not write down.
Example:   Log.i(TAG, MSG);
To make sure it works, we can add some text to MSG

```
 Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s %s", "MSG>" , MSG));
```

Comment: Thanks. Good info. Turns our my ```strResponse``` is not being assigned. Not a problem with android studio but the HttpPost Response is truly empty. Still a problem for me but that concludes this post.